# Sorting in ascending order an array of integers in Java

Tags: java, sorting

How do I put in ascending order an array of integers in Java?
I have class and Pilha.java Ordenacao.Java, but the program is not working.

#### Pilha.java

```
package lista03Pilhas;

public class Pilha {

    // indica qual o tamanho maximo da pilha (tamanho maximo do vetor)
    private int tamanhoMaximo;
    // indica o topo da pilha (quantidade de itens do vetor)
    private int topo;
    // cria o vetor que ira implementar a pilha
    private Object[] vetorPilha;
    // construtor que recebe como parametro o tamanho da pilha (tamanho do vetor)

    public Pilha(int length) {
        // indica o tamanho da pilha (vetor)
        tamanhoMaximo = length;
        // instancia o vetor com o tamanho informado
        vetorPilha = new Object[length];
        // faz com que o apontador do topo indique que não há elementos na pilha
        topo = -1;
    }

    // funcao que insere um objeto no topo da pilha
    public void push(Object obj) {
        // incrementa o topo (desloca para cima)
        topo++;
        // coloca o novo objeto na pilha
        vetorPilha[topo] = obj;
    }

    // funcao que remove um objeto do topo da pilha
    public Object pop() {

        // verifica se a pilha esta vazia
        if (topo < 0) {
            return null;
        } else {

            // obtem o objeto do topo da pilha
            Object auxiliar = vetorPilha[topo];

            // decrementa o topo (desce um item na pilha)
            topo--;

            // retorna o elemento do topo da pilha
            return auxiliar;
        }
    }

    // funcao que verifica quem esta no topo da pilha
    public Object top() {

        // verifica se a pilha esta vazia
        if (topo < 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return vetorPilha[topo];
        }
    }

    // verifica se a pilha esta vazia
    public boolean isEmpty() {

        // verifica se o topo aponta para algum indice valido do vetor
        if (topo == -1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // verifica se a pilha esta cheia
    public boolean isFull() {

        // verifica se o topo aponta para o ultimo elemento do vetor
        if (topo == tamanhoMaximo - 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Ordenacao.java

```
package lista03Pilhas;

public class Ordenacao {

    public static int[] ordenarDecrescente(int v[]) {
        Pilha minhaPilha = new Pilha(v.length);
        recebePilha(minhaPilha);
        int vetor[] = new int[v.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            vetor[i] = v[i];
            minhaPilha.push(vetor[i]);

        }
        int u = ((Integer) minhaPilha.pop()).intValue();
        return vetor;
    }

    public static void recebePilha(Pilha pilha){

    }
}
```

#### Main.java

```
package lista03Pilhas;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lista03Pilhas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int v[] = new int[]{100, 20, 15, 9, 8, 7, 1};
        System.out.println("Vetor:" + Arrays.toString(Ordenacao.ordenarDecrescente(v)));

        int p;
        int m;

        Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] ordenarDecrescente = Ordenacao.ordenarDecrescente(v);
        Pilha minhaPilha = new Pilha(v.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            minhaPilha.push(v[i]);
            Object menor = minhaPilha.pop();
            System.out.print(minhaPilha.pop());
        }
        System.out.println("");
        for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(v[i] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the sorting part in the whole code you posted?

Answer (score 6):

> How do I put in ascending order an array of integers in Java?

By using [`Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
int[] arr = ...;
Arrays.sort(arr);
```

Comment: Please link to the latest Javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use `Arrays.sort()` with an appropriate `Comparator`. The default comparator works in ascending order, so it's just a matter of using [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int%5b%5d%29) method.

Answer (score 1):

Java uses Quick sort for sorting of primitive types and merge sort for sorting of Objects, I think it is good to use Arrays.sort() to sort arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are looking for something like the Bubble algorithm...

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use the "Array.sort()" method of the java.lang class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Arrays.sort(int[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])).

In Java 6 the sorting algorithm used for this method is a
**Tuned quicksort**, adapted from Jon L. Bentley and M. Douglas McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function", Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 23(11) P. 1249-1265 (November 1993).

In Java 7 and 8, the sorting algorithm used for this method is a
**Dual-Pivot Quicksort** by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch.